# Query two tables with Laravel and two WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have table `orders` and table `payments`. I want to query table `orders`, joining table `payments` and to show with an order is paid and which isn't.

This is Order model

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'orders';
     protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';

     public function paidorders() {
         return $this->hasMany('payments', 'processed');
     }
}
```

This is Payment model

```
class Payment extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'payments';
     protected $primaryKey = 'paymentID';

     public function orders()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('Order', 'user_id');
     }
}
```

And the User model

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('Order', 'user_id');
}
```

This is how I show currently orders only without status paid/not paid.

```
  $orders = self::$user->orders()->get();
     return View::make('site.users.orders', [
        'orders' => $orders
     ]);
```

This is the query but I don't know how to implement it in Laravel

```
SELECT orders. * , payments. * 
FROM orders
   INNER JOIN payments ON orders.user_id = payments.userID
WHERE orders.user_id =2
AND payments.userID =2
```

`self::$user->...` is the logged user. How will be used this in the `WHERE` clause?

I don't get it exactly how to build this query

UPDATE `dd($orders)`

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#264 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Order)#260 (20) { ["table":protected]=> string(6) "orders" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(8) "order_id" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["processed"]=> string(1) "1" } ["original":protected]=> array(1) { ["processed"]=> string(1) "1" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) } } }
```

Comment: Payment has many orders? shouldn't this be belongs to Order?

Comment: May be yes.. But still I'm not very good in Laravel and don't understand how to build the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = Order::select(DB::Raw('payments.processed'))
    ->join('payments', 'orders.order_id', '=', 'payments.orderID')
    ->where('orders.user_id',  2)
    ->where('payments.userID', 2)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I've added dump of orders. I can see `["processed"]=> string(1) "1"` in the dump which is the value in database

Comment: Please share the full dump result

Comment: This is the full dump of `$orders`

Comment: It must be object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114933/discussion-between-calin-blaga-and-jordan-vit).

Answer (score 7):

```
Try this query code:-

$users = DB::table('orders')
            ->join('payments', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'payments.userID')
            ->where('orders.user_id', '2')
            ->where('payments.userID', '2')
            ->select('orders.*', 'payments.*')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I believe op wants to use Eloquent

Comment: Yes, and with this I've got `'Call to undefined method stdClass::getOrderData()'`

Comment: Yes, and I get this error `'Call to undefined method stdClass::getOrderData()'`

Comment: Ok The array returns in Object format, You have also checked the query just replace ->get() with this ->toSql()

Comment: I don't know if it's matters but I don't pass user id via url/button.. I pass `csrf token`..